# Zebra-styling my table rows

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with zebra-style tables. I need only my content to be in that zebra style (black and white lines) not the things above it (zebra patern needs to start UNDER "present dans domaine, second and third table"

www.jsfiddle.net/1k0oet48/

Comment: Your html seems invalid. You have divs, encapsulating <tr>. I'm not sure if that's allowed. Also, your tr:nth.... css it applied to the whole table. .zebra class could be applied on a tr and css could be written accordingly

Comment: yes the html layout isnt correct.. you need to wrap content accordingly, use table>thead+tbody+tfoot and target only tbody > tr accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some classes to the table and you can select it correctly.

```css
body, nav ul  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {    
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #111;
  vertical-align: top;
  top: -1px;
  opacity: 0.15;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

nav:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: 0.01s;
 background-color: #111;
 transition: 0.3s;
 
}

.nav a {
  display: block; 
  background: #111; 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.7em 1.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 85%;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav{  
  vertical-align: top; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav > li { 
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 1px; 
} 

.nav li:hover > a { 
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color:#302f2f;
  color: #40d23b; 
}

 .nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #81D4FA;
  border-top: none;
}
.nav > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.nav > li li:hover > ul { 
  left: 100%;
  top:-1px;
}

.nav > li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;  
}

.nav li li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent; 
  right: 10px;
}

.prve{
  max-width:120px;
  min-width: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #81D4FA;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.druhe {
  max-width: 140px;
  min-width: 105px;
  border-right: 2px solid #81D4FA;
}

.content {
 position: static;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.header {
 text-align: center;
 position: static;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
th, td{
  border:1px solid black;
}

table{
 table-layout: fixed;
 min-width: 1300px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}
/*ZISTIT PRECO NEJDE ZEBRA RIADKOVANIE TUTO*/
.three-th-table tr:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.two-th-table tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

td:nth-child(even):hover {
 background-color: #b7b7b7;
}

td:nth-child(odd):hover {
 background-color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
 <body>
<!--MENU BAR!-->
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav">
    <li class="prve"><a href="#">Dátumy</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1-7/7/2016</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#172016">1/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#272016">2/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#372016">3/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#472016">4/7/2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#572016">5/7/2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#672016">6/7/2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#772016">7/7/2016</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
      <li><a href="#">8-14/7/2016</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">8/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">9/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">11/7/2016</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12/7/2016</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">13/7/2016</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14/7/2016</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">15-21/7/2016</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">15/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">9/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10/7/2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">11/7/2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">12/7/2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">13/7/2016</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14/7/2016</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>      
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="druhe"><a href="#">&#9776</a>
  <ul>
      <li> <a href="flv.html"> FLV </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="flc.html"> FLC </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="qua.html"> QUA </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="hfx.html"> HFX </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="pdt.html"> PDT </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="rsh.html"> RSH </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="bur.html"> BUR </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="suhrn.html"> SUHRN </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="inci.html"> INCI </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="jira.html"> JIRA </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="chgt.html"> CHGT </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="task.html"> TASK </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="vrs.html"> VRS </a> </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="content">
  
   <div class="header">
    <h1>RPO quotidienne SI </h1>
   </div>
    
   <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <a name="172016">
   <!--tabulka 1-->
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="three-th-table">
    <tr>
  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left">DATE</th>
  <th colspan="2">20/7/2016</th>
  <th>streda</th>
  <th colspan="8">e-version: http://docinfogroupe.inetpsa.com/ead/dom/401334893.fd              </th>
  <th colspan="2"> SEMAINE </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #d0e6ff" height="25px"> Leader T. Simoncik </th>
  <th  colspan="9" style="background-color: #d0bad8"> SI Flux - FLX </th>
  <th colspan="2"  style="background-color: #d0e6ff"> FLV </th>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Presents dans domaine</td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px solid black" >3</td>
  <td colspan="4"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Total PSI dans domaine</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 2px solid black">4</td>
  <td colspan="5"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Simoncik 482892, Kodrla 482904, Vajs 482915, Hrebicek 482168</td>
 </tr>
 <div  class="zebra">
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06128770</td>
  <td colspan="10"> 11.07.2016,NEO/FLV,De 16h à 18h : Mise en place du Patch ORACLE (EXADATA) dans EXADATA,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">HREBICEK</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,PISSARO,Ziadost o zmenu atributu, B6 taha do boxu na retus, lakovna sa ma vyjadrit</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">KODRLA</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,NOREV,Upratovanie tried (obligatoire, preparation,...),</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">SIMONCIK</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,ARCHIMEDE,Analyza + riesenie zona automatizacie - zobrazovanie na panely podla ref,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr> 
   </table>
  </div>
</a>
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <a name="1072016">
   <!--tabulka 2-->
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="two-th-table">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #d0e6ff" height="25px"> Leader T. Simoncik </th>
  <th  colspan="9" style="background-color: #d0bad8"> SI Flux - FLX </th>
  <th colspan="2"  style="background-color: #d0e6ff"> FLC </th>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Presents dans domaine</td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px solid black" >3</td>
  <td colspan="4"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Total PSI dans domaine</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 2px solid black">3</td>
  <td colspan="5"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Bednarikova 483017, Dobrikova 482545, Duracka 482158</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06107245</td>
  <td colspan="10">11.07.2016,FAKIR/PO,FAKIR-PO : INSTALLATION V4.0 2016-07-11 08:30:00 INDISPO 2 h,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06121081</td>
  <td colspan="10" >11.07.2016,CLOE,CLOE - MISE EN PLACE BATCH CORAIL-ERP MG 2016-07-11 15:00:00,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06121354</td>
  <td colspan="10" >12.07.2016,CORAIL/ERP,instalacia verzie CORAIL/ERP v1.7.0.15.4 ,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">DOBRIKOVA</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,CORAIL/ERP,Rituel CORAIL VCO PFA / PSI,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">DURACKA</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,,PB s EDI pre B6 - riesi Roman,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr> 
   </table>
   </div>
   </a>
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <a name="1072016">
   <!--tabulka 3-->
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="two-th-table">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #d0e6ff" height="25px"> Leader T. Simoncik </th>
  <th  colspan="9" style="background-color: #d0bad8"> SI Flux - FLX </th>
  <th colspan="2"  style="background-color: #d0e6ff"> FLC </th>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Presents dans domaine</td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px solid black" >3</td>
  <td colspan="4"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Total PSI dans domaine</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 2px solid black">3</td>
  <td colspan="5"  style="border-bottom: 2px solid black">Bednarikova 483017, Dobrikova 482545, Duracka 482158</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06107245</td>
  <td colspan="10">11.07.2016,FAKIR/PO,FAKIR-PO : INSTALLATION V4.0 2016-07-11 08:30:00 INDISPO 2 h,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06121081</td>
  <td colspan="10" >11.07.2016,CLOE,CLOE - MISE EN PLACE BATCH CORAIL-ERP MG 2016-07-11 15:00:00,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">CHGT06121354</td>
  <td colspan="10" >12.07.2016,CORAIL/ERP,instalacia verzie CORAIL/ERP v1.7.0.15.4 ,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">C</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">DOBRIKOVA</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,CORAIL/ERP,Rituel CORAIL VCO PFA / PSI,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center"> T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2">DURACKA</td>
  <td colspan="10" >,,,PB s EDI pre B6 - riesi Roman,</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">T</td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #f7dbe5"></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="10" ></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"></td>
  <td> <form action="" style="text-align:center"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box"></form></td>
 </tr> 
     </table>
     </div>
    </a>        
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```